# multiples sumas en una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo 1 tabla en mysql donde tengo la información de personas que tienen un adeudo de una tienda de ropa de varios años, lo que quiero es una consulta que me de el nombre de la persona y que se sume su adeudo.

Ejemplo de la tabla y sus datos:

```
nombre |  año | monto
Pepe   | 2011 | 100.00
Pepe   | 2012 | 300.00
Pepe   | 2016 | 900.00
Maria  | 2011 | 100.00
Maria  | 2012 | 530.00
```

Resultado:

```
Pepe  | 2011 | 13000.00
Maria  | 2012 | 630.00
```

El año no importa sólo quiero la suma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con la función [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum). Considera que `SUM` es una función de agrupación, por lo que se necesita una sentencia [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) que indique los campos que serán agrupados para realizar la suma.

Aquí el ejemplo de cómo luciría.

```
SELECT nombre, SUM(monto)
FROM tuTabla
GROUP BY nombre
ORDER BY nombre
```

Comment: ooh muchísimas gracias :D